# pyplot legend not matching lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

My legend doesn't match the line colors.  Any idea how I go about fixing this and what I am doing wrong?  The code downloads the data from yahoo finance so you should be able to run it as is on your machine and see the data yourself.  Thanks for your help!

```
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start = '5/1/2007'
end = '10/1/2007'
event = datetime.date(2007,6,27)
companies = ['AAPL','MSFT','BBRY','IBM']

all_data = {}
for ticker in companies:
        all_data[ticker] = web.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start,end)

price = pd.DataFrame({tic:data['Adj Close']
                    for tic, data in all_data.iteritems()})

volume = pd.DataFrame({tic:data['Volume']
                    for tic, data in all_data.iteritems()})

rels = price/price.ix[event]
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
for i in companies:
   plt.plot(rels.index,rels[i],label=i,lw=4.0)  
plt.legend(companies,loc='upper left')
plt.axvline(x=event)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Edit: I noticed that the legend was picking up the axvline so I moved that to after the legend and generated separate plot statements via loop as suggested in the comments but it still looks like the lines aren't matching the correct names in the legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've labelled your lines with your call  to `plt.plot` so you don't need to pass another load of labels with your call to `plt.legend`. In other words replace

```
plt.legend(companies,loc='upper left')
```

with

```
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
```

and things should work fine.